# Slider que cambie de imágenes automáticamente y mediante el uso de flechas

Tags: javascript, web, slider

Soy consciente que existe infinidades de sliders, pero lo que busco es lo mas simple posible sin siquiera el uso de librerías, he intentado durante varios días fusionar dos códigos distintos(un slider que cambia automáticamente y otro mediante el uso de flechas) pero sin éxito, así que lo colocaré a continuación para que puedan orientarme. Recién estoy empezando con js por eso busco lo mas sencillo para poder progresar y entender mejor el código. Gracias.
Nota: he intentado pasar por parámetros los valores de la función `function plusSlides(n)` a la funcion `function showSlides(n)` pero termina mal y no cambia ninguna imagen luego. Así que publicare mi avance desde este error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://www.eltiempo.com/files/article_content/uploads/2019/05/30/5cefe5a8435e5.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">[0]</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/600x315/03/1f/70/031f70daf1ee5c8b3ad17418f9e39742.jpg" style="width:100%">

  <div class="text">[1]</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/69/31/4e/69314ec93e41ee3846618c9fae493db3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">[2]</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>
<script>
 var n = 0;
var index = 0;
showSlides(n);

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  index++;
  if (index> slides.length) {
    index = 1
    }  
    index = index + n;    
  slides[index-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(showSlides, 4000);
}

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(n);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algunas cosas por mejorar y solo agregar una función:

- Declarar globalmente variables necesarias: index (que debe comenzar en cero), sliders (asignar solo una vez al cargar el DOM), timer (para controlar el temporizador), next y prev (para comportamiento de botones)
- No es necesaria la variable `n` porque la función debe recibirla como parámetro
- Tampoco es necesaria la función `plusSlides()`, se puede llamar directamente a `showSlides()`
- Solo en la carga del DOM se recorren todos los elementos para ocultarlos
- Dentro de la función se cancela el temporizador, para garantizar que la duración siempre es la misma cuando no hay intervención del usuario
- Luego, se oculta el elemento que está visible y se muestra el seleccionado
- Agregar función para "escuchar" teclas presionadas y activar slider con flechas izquierda y derecha

```js
let index = 0,
  sliders,
  timer,
  next,
  prev;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Obtener elementos solo una vez y ocultarlos
  slides = document.querySelectorAll(".mySlides");
  for(let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  // Obtener botones y asignar evento
  document.querySelector('.prev').addEventListener('click', () => showSlides(-1));
  document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', () => showSlides(1));
  // Asignar evento para funcionar con teclado
  document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
      // Tecla izquierda
      showSlides(-1);
    } else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
      // Tecla derecha
      showSlides(1);
    }
  });
  showSlides(0);
});

function showSlides(n) {
  // Cancelar temporizador para evitar comportamientos extraños
  clearTimeout(timer);
  // Ocultar elemento actual
  slides[index].style.display = 'none';
  index += n;
  if (index >= slides.length) {
    // Ir al inicio
    index = 0;
  } else if(index < 0) {
    // Ir al final
    index = slides.length - 1;
  }
  // Mostrar elemento
  slides[index].style.display = "block";  
  timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 4000, 1);
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://www.eltiempo.com/files/article_content/uploads/2019/05/30/5cefe5a8435e5.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">[0]</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/600x315/03/1f/70/031f70daf1ee5c8b3ad17418f9e39742.jpg" style="width:100%">

  <div class="text">[1]</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/69/31/4e/69314ec93e41ee3846618c9fae493db3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">[2]</div>
</div>

<a class="prev">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next">&#10095;</a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!, me soluciono perfectamente lo que necesitaba, estuve estudiando el código y hay ciertas partes que no logro entender del todo y tampoco he encontrado ejemplos de ellos, si me pudieras explicar por favor. Por ejemplo `'DOMContentLoaded'` sobre este no encontrado nada, despues en la siguiente linea de codigo  `document.querySelector('.prev').addEventListener('click', () => showSlides(-1));` espcificamente esto no entiendo `() =>` , por lo que estuve mirando y estudiando, por que no debería ir direcamente asi `addEventListener('click', showSlides(-1));`  ? . Gracias. @Triby

Comment: [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) es un evento que se dispara cuando se carga el DOM, garantizando que los elementos ya están disponibles. [`() =>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) es una forma de "simplificar" el códgo. Si especificas directamente la función con, paréntesis y parámetro, se va a ejecutar desde que asignas el evento.

Comment: _"Si especificas directamente la función con, paréntesis y parámetro, se va a ejecutar desde que asignas el evento"_ , ¿Cuál seria la consecuencia de colocarlo directamente?, ya que a modo de prueba, he colocado la función directamente y los botones de flechas no responden. @Triby

Comment: ah y un detalle mas, ¿a que hace referencia el parámetro `1` que pasaste`timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 4000, 1);`  ?. @Triby

Comment: Al parecer, no se asigna, simplemente se ejecuta, por lo que debes usar: `.addEventListener('click', nombreDeFuncionSinParentesis);` o función anónima ``.addEventListener('click', function() { ... } );`` o función flecha ``.addEventListener('click', () => { ... } );``, en esta última las llaves son opcionales cuando solo incluye una instrucción.

Comment: El 1 es el parámetro que debe recibir la función: [`setTimeout(nombreDeFuncion, tiempoDeEspera, parametro1, parametro2, ... parametroX);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).